# Unit test a method with a call to a private callback using Mockito|Android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to unit test the following method in Android:

```
@Override
public void onTryAgain() {
    mView.showLoading();

    mGetLoginSsoUseCase.execute(
            getLoginSsoLink(),
            new GetSsoLinkUseCase.Params(mUrl));
}
```

In which getLoginSsoLink() returns a callback object:

```
private ICallback<GetLoginSsoLinkResult> getLoginSsoLink() {
    return new ICallback<GetLoginSsoLinkResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(GetLoginSsoLinkResult result) {
            // some code
        }

        @Override
        public void onKoError(KOException exception) {
            // some code
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectivityError(ConnectivityException exception) {
            // some code
        }

        @Override
        public void onGenericError(Exception exception) {
            // some code
        }
    };
}
```

My unit test using Mockito is like that:

```
@Test
public void WhenCallOnTryAgain_ThenShowLoadingIsCalledInView(){

    doNothing().when(mGetSsoLinkUseCase).execute(
            FAKE_GET_LOGIN_SSO_LINK_RESULT_CALLBACK,
            FAKE_GET_SSO_LINK_USE_CASE_PARAMS);

    mPresenter.onTryAgain();

    verify(mGetSsoLinkUseCase).execute(
            FAKE_GET_LOGIN_SSO_LINK_RESULT_CALLBACK,
            FAKE_GET_SSO_LINK_USE_CASE_PARAMS);
}
```

Where the fake vars are:

```
private static final ICallback<GetLoginSsoLinkResult> FAKE_GET_LOGIN_SSO_LINK_RESULT_CALLBACK =
        new ICallback<GetLoginSsoLinkResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GetLoginSsoLinkResult result) {}

            @Override
            public void onKoError(KOException exception) {}

            @Override
            public void onConnectivityError(ConnectivityException exception) {}

            @Override
            public void onGenericError(Exception exception) {}
        };
private static final GetSsoLinkUseCase.Params FAKE_GET_SSO_LINK_USE_CASE_PARAMS =
        new GetSsoLinkUseCase.Params(FAKE_SSO_URL);
```

If I run the test, I get the following error:

> Argument(s) are different! Wanted: mGetSsoLinkUseCase.execute(
>       com.xxx.xxxforstores.presenter.LoginSsoPresenterTest$1@8317c52,
>       com.xxx.xxxforstores.domain.usecase.GetSsoLinkUseCase$Params@68e965f5
>   );
>   -> at com.xxx.xxxforstores.presenter.LoginSsoPresenterTest.WhenCallOnTryAgain_ThenShowLoadingIsCalledInView(LoginSsoPresenterTest.java:111)
>   Actual invocation has different arguments: mGetSsoLinkUseCase.execute(
>       com.xxx.xxxforstores.mvp.presenter.LoginSsoPresenter$1@76f2bbc1,
>       com.xxx.xxxforstores.domain.usecase.GetSsoLinkUseCase$Params@6f27a732
>   );
>   -> at com.xxx.xxxforstores.mvp.presenter.LoginSsoPresenter.onTryAgain(LoginSsoPresenter.java:115)
>
> Comparison Failure:
>
> Argument(s) are different! Wanted: mGetSsoLinkUseCase.execute(
>       com.xxx.xzzforstores.presenter.LoginSsoPresenterTest$1@8317c52,
>      com.xxx.xxzforstores.domain.usecase.GetSsoLinkUseCase$Params@68e965f5
>   );
>   -> at com.xxx.xxxforstores.presenter.LoginSsoPresenterTest.WhenCallOnTryAgain_ThenShowLoadingIsCalledInView(LoginSsoPresenterTest.java:111)
>   Actual invocation has different arguments: mGetSsoLinkUseCase.execute(
>       com.xxx.xxxforstores.mvp.presenter.LoginSsoPresenter$1@76f2bbc1,
>       com.xxx.xxxforstores.domain.usecase.GetSsoLinkUseCase$Params@6f27a732
>   );
>   -> at com.xxx.xxxforstores.mvp.presenter.LoginSsoPresenter.onTryAgain(LoginSsoPresenter.java:115)
>
> at
>   com.xxx.xxxforstores.presenter.LoginSsoPresenterTest.WhenCallOnTryAgain_ThenShowLoadingIsCalledInView(LoginSsoPresenterTest.java:111)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:84)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
>     at
>   org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:161)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)

I have a little experience in unit test so I figure that I am probably doing something wrong, what I have to change to test a method like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** If `mGetLoginSsoUseCase` is a mock then you do not really need to set-up the `.execute` method with `doNothing`. Nothing will happen by default anyway

**2)** You cant really go for exact objects in the `verify` as one of the params is simply created on the fly: `new GetSsoLinkUseCase.Params(mUrl)`. I would go for `any(class)` checks which should be enough in your case:

```
verify(mGetSsoLinkUseCase).execute(
            Mockito.any(ICallback.class),
            Mockito.any(GetSsoLinkUseCase.Params.class));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. There is a way to verify with concrete objects, but you would need to refactor.. and its questionable the worth